Efficient counting of integer solutions to linear system
In my research, I have a particular 18x18 matrix $\mathbf{A}$ which defines the linear system $\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{-1}$ over the nonnegative integers. And I'm interested in computing the complete pareto frontier of the system , that is to say the set of all "primitive" solutions $\mathbf{x}$ which cannot be decomposed as $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}^\prime +\mathbf{y}$ with $\mathbf{x}^\prime$ a strictly smaller solution and $\mathbf{y}$ a nonnegative vector.
For general $\mathbf{A}$, this is hard to compute: Dickson's lemma guarantees that the set of such minimal solutions is finite, but this is not much practical reassurance. I am currently using a branch-and-bound method to find them all, albeit inefficiently.
My question is this: My matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is not arbitrary, but is in fact the difference of two binary matrices, meaning that every entry is in $\{-1, 0, +1\}$. I am wondering what the state of the art is on computing the pareto frontier for such a special case---if there is an obviously more efficient method that takes advantage of the structure of this problem (nonnegative integer solutions, linear objective, approximately binary matrix.)
(That is my main question, but barring a solution there, I would also be interested in making inroads on the combinatorics of this problem---do we know any bounds on the number of pareto optimal solutions in this case, even if computing them is hard?)
Edit: Here is a representative $\mathbf{A}$, with plus, minus, and blank denoting +1, -1, and 0 for concision:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 & & & & & & & & & & & &- & & & &- & \\
 &- &- & &+ &+ & & & & & &+ &- & &- & &+ & \\
 &+ &- & &- & & & & & & & &+ & &- & & & \\
 & &+ &- &- & & & & &+ & & & & &- & & & \\
 &- &+ & &- & & &- & &- & &- &+ & &- & &- & \\
 &- &- & &+ &- & & & &+ & & & & &+ & &- & \\
+ & & & & &+ & &- & &- &- &- &+ & & &+ &+ &- \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &- & \\
 & & & & & & & & &- & & & & & & & & \\
 & & &- &+ & &+ & & & & &+ &- & & & &- & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &- & & \\
 &- & & &+ & &- &- & &- &+ & & & & &+ &- &- \\
 &+ & & & &+ &- & & &+ & &+ & & & & &- & \\
- & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &- \\
 & & & & & &- & & & &+ & & & & &- & &- \\
 &- &- &- & &+ & & & & & & &+ & & & &- &+ \\
 &- & & & & &+ &- & & & & & & &+ &+ &- &
\end{bmatrix}$$
Alternatively, here is a plain text representation of $A$:
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  
  0 -1 -1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0 -1  0  1  0  
  0  1 -1  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0 -1  0  0  0  
  0  0  1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  
  0 -1  1  0 -1  0  0 -1  0 -1  0 -1  1  0 -1  0 -1  0  
  0 -1 -1  0  1 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0 -1  0  
  1  0  0  0  0  1  0 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  1  0  0  1  1 -1  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
  0  0  0 -1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0 -1  0  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  
  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1 -1  0 -1  1  0  0  0  0  1 -1 -1  
  0  1  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0  
 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  
  0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0 -1  0 -1  
  0 -1 -1 -1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0 -1  1  
  0 -1  0  0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1 -1  0 


Can you please share the matrix?

I'd start with trying specialized tools for computing integral points in polyhedra - e.g., Normaliz

@RobPratt Done! Took me a sec to figure out how to typeset it so it fit on the page.

@MaxAlekseyev Great! I hadn't heard of Normaliz; so far, it looks like it can work with integral points in unbounded polyhedra, which is excellent. I am looking into it.

Because columns 9 and 14 are empty, you can fix $x_j=0$ for $j\in{9,14}$.

Isn't this just counting integer points in a polyhedron? This has a huge theory, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_points_in_convex_polyhedra or this book by Barvinok: https://ems.press/books/zlam/50.

@domotorp Thanks! I'll follow up on that book. I'm basically counting the number of hilbert basis elements of a convex cone. My specific question was about whether the slightly special {-1,0,+1} form of the matrix made it easier to calculate this, but given that normaliz seems to have efficient general-purpose algorithms, it may just be sufficient.

@user326210: Although the Hilbert basis and the Pareto frontier (mentioned in your question) are related, they are not the same thing. I'd suggest you to clarify the question on whether you want the Hilbert basis, or the Pareto frontier (or both).

Sure! I care only about the Pareto frontier, though I didn't notice the connection to the hilbert basis before. Normaliz computes it with beautiful efficiency and solves my problem; in practice I can just filter for the pareto frontier, which I believe is a subset: $$C/(C+ (\mathbb{R}^k_+/{0})) \subseteq C/(C+(C/{0}))$$

I've discussed this problem privately with Winfried Bruns (the author of Normaliz), and what follows is the courtesy of Winfried:

The inequalities define a rational polyhedron $P$. It is unbounded. We want
to find a minimal system of generators of the set $S$ of lattice points in
$P$ with respect to the action of the semigroup $L$ of integral vectors in
the positive orthant. Normaliz
can do the hard part of the computation. It must then be followed by
rather easy postprocessing. (The postprocessing could be replaced by a
second run of Normaliz.)
The polyhedron $P$ has a natural cone associated to it, the recession
cone. It is the cone of infinite directions in the polyhedron. In other
words, it is the maximal cone $C$ such that $P + C \subset P$. The
semigroup $M$ of integral vectors in $C$ operates on the set $S$ by
addition. Note that $M$ is a proper subsemigroup of $L$.
The input file hilb_problem.in contains the inequalities and options.
If you run it by
/path/to/normaliz -c hilb_problem.in

We assume it is in the current directory. (The option -c generates
terminal output.) Normaliz computes the (automatically finite) minimal system $G$ of generators of $S$ with respect to action of $M$ (and not with that of $L$).
The computation of $G$ is running on our server, but will take long time,
say 2 or 3 weeks. Suppose we have $G$. I think it is best then to minimize
$G$ with respect to the action of $L$: form the differences $x-y$ for $x,y$ in $G$, $x \neq y$, and if $x-y$ has nonnegative entries, discard $x$.
